# How can I prevent third party websites from using my images?

Tags: wordpress, seo, spam

I have a WordPress website. Some spammy websites (spam score 70% - 90%) use my website image link directly on their websites due to which I am getting spammy backlinks and spam score of my website is increasing.

Is there a solution that doesn't affect my website?

Comment: What is a *'spammy'* website?

Answer (score 0):

Preventing hotlinking is doable, and there are a few options.

> Hotlinking is the act of linking to a file that is hosted on another site, instead of downloading the file, hosting it on your own server, and providing proper citation. Images are most frequently hotlinked, but audio files, movies, flash animations, and other digital assets can also be hotlinked.

Source:
https://blog.hubspot.com/website/hotlinking